# What could be the validation rule, so that new account can only be added if date is even

Tags: validation-rule

I am new to salesforce and is practicing new things to increase my knowledge. I came across scenario where only account can be added if date is even. For the same, I have created Date__c field in account object. I tried solving this by using MOD but MOD can be used on number and not on Date. How can we validate this. I tried doing following

DAY(Date__c )/2 <> 0 but it is showing error on every Date I add.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This question would be improved if you [edit] it to show us what you've tried so far. Also, what research have you done? If you look through [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5), do you see anything that might be useful? (hint: there is an easy way to get the individual date components)

Comment: Thanks @DerekF I have edited my question with what I have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close.

`DAY()` extracts the day of the month, which gives you the number you'd need to provide to `MOD()`.

Dividing by 2 would get you a whole, but nonzero, number. MOD() would give you a 1 (for odd days) and a 0 (for even days)

`MOD(DAY(Date__c), 2) = 1` is what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried using MOD with my rule but it was erroring out number can not be used with date datatype but i guess i was not using = 1 or 0 with it. This code has worked. Thanks

Comment: @GSingh Again, `MOD()` requires 2 numbers, which is why you also need to use `DAY()` (to extract the day of the month _as a number_). `MOD(Date__c, 2)` is not valid syntax because _Date and Number are two different data types_, and the function signature (for lack of a better term) of MOD is `MOD(Number, Number)`. The documentation I linked you to in my comment does tell you this and gives some examples. When you're running into issues with formulae, looking at that documentation should always be your first stop.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)!

You were *almost* there....

With the formula you tried, the reason it is erroring on every date you enter is because it will *never* equal zero.

For example, if the `DAY` is "1" - the lowest it can be - then `DAY(Date__c)/2` will return "0.5". But even if you were to limit the output to zero decimal places, then `DAY(Date__c)/2` will equal "1".  It will never equal zero.

- You were correct in your idea to use `MOD`, and you are correct in that it can only be used on a **number**.
- You were also correct in your thought of using `DAY`, since it

> Returns a day of the month in the form of a **number** between 1 and 31. *

*[Emphasis added.]*

Try:

```
MOD(
  DAY(Date__c),
  2
) = 1
```

---

* *https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm*

Answer (score 0):

```
OR(
DAY(Date__c) = 2, 
DAY(Date__c) = 4, 
DAY(Date__c) = 6, 
DAY(Date__c) = 8,
DAY(Date__c) = 10,
DAY(Date__c) = 12,
DAY(Date__c) = 14,
DAY(Date__c) = 18,
DAY(Date__c) = 20,
DAY(Date__c) = 22,
DAY(Date__c) = 24,
DAY(Date__c) = 26,
DAY(Date__c) = 28,
DAY(Date__c) = 30
)
```

Comment: Since a Validation Rule only "kicks in" if the formula evaluates to TRUE, when using multiple `OR`s you do not need to surround them with an `IF..., TRUE, FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks Moonpie. I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: This would work, but is way longer than it needs to be.